# Add rows with td indexes considering thead and tbody

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a toolbar to modify the table `table_content_inv`.

Column management works, but it is the rows that cause me problems, whether it is adding or removing. It is because I specify a **thead** and a **tbody** which cause troubles with **indexes**. When I select an element of thead (row index 0), it will be added to the tbody (row index 0) - I know it's me who specified it but I don't know how to proceed.

I get the indexes of the tds with the function .index() without managing if the element is in thead or tbody. 
Should I change the way I retrieve the indexes (or something else) from the td elements or somehow add the fact that it's either the element is in thead or tbody?

```js
//set selected row
var rowIndex = '';
$(document).on('click', '#table_content_inv td', function() {
  rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
});

//delete selected row 
$(document).on('click', '#button_del_row', function() {
  $('#table_content_inv > tbody > tr').eq(rowIndex).remove();
});

//add row to table
$(document).on('click', '#button_add_row', function() {
  var indexNewRow = rowIndex + 1;
  var newRow = '<tr>';

  var colCount = document.getElementById('table_content_inv').rows[0].cells.length;
  for (i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    newRow += '<td>new entry</td>';
  }
  newRow += '</tr>';

  $('#table_content_inv > tbody > tr').eq(rowIndex).after(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_content_inv">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>entry</td>
      <td>entry</td>
      <td>entry</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>entry</td>
      <td>entry</td>
      <td>entry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>entry</td>
      <td>entry</td>
      <td>entry</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="toolbar-content" class="toolbar-content">
    <button id="button_add_row" class="button button-secondary" type="button">Ajout ligne</button>                
    <button id="button_del_row" class="button button-secondary" type="button">Supprimer ligne</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are the buttons in the HTML?

Comment: Just added @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `index()`... I suggest you to use a class to "select" a row. It even can be used to actually highlight it. But also to target it from the add/delete handlers.

See below.

Notice that I add `tbody` in the row click selectors... So the headers cannot be selected.

```js
//set selected row
$(document).on('click', '#table_content_inv tbody td', function() { 
  // Some highlighting... ;)
  $("tr").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).closest('tr').addClass("selected");
});

//delete selected row using the .selected class
$(document).on('click', '#button_del_row', function() {
  $(".selected").remove();
});

//add row to table after the .selected class
$(document).on('click', '#button_add_row', function() {

  var newRow = '<tr>';
  var colCount = document.getElementById('table_content_inv').rows[0].cells.length;
  for (i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    newRow += '<td>new entry</td>';
  }
  newRow += '</tr>';

  $(".selected").after(newRow);
  // Remove the highlighting.
  $("tr").removeClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_content_inv">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>header</td>
      <td>header</td>
      <td>header</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>entry1</td>
      <td>entry1</td>
      <td>entry1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>entry2</td>
      <td>entry2</td>
      <td>entry2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="toolbar-content" class="toolbar-content">
    <button id="button_add_row" class="button button-secondary" type="button">Ajout ligne</button>                
    <button id="button_del_row" class="button button-secondary" type="button">Supprimer ligne</button>
</div>
```